# find algebraic integers in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ where x is a root of unity

Tags: field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

prove that the set of algebraic integers in$\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]$ are exactly $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$where $\zeta_p$ is a primitive p-th root of unity(may assume p is prime)

I'm sure that the problem is solvable when p is prime(also, in this case the question seems easier )

I have tried to solve this problem by using Galois group，but it turned out that the proof is incorrect. I think I need to change my method but I have no idea about it

Aany advice will be helpful,Thank you.

Comment: Hi, What have you tried ? Also see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question, people are more inclined to help you if you write what you've tried.

Comment: @EDX thank you for your comment

Comment: This is quite a non-trivial result. It's actually easier to prove that these algebraic integers are in $\Bbb Z[\lambda]$ where $\lambda=(\zeta_p-1)$ where we can exploit the fact that $\lambda$'s minimal polynomial satisfies Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: @Angina Seng There are some basic facts I know:The elements in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$are all algebraic integers    and    The minimal polynomial of $\zeta_p$is $\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}x^i$(by using Eisenstein's criterion or the Galois group $Gal(\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]|\mathbb{Q}))$   It seems that you have a quite deep understanding of this problem，I'm more than glad if you could provide a more detailed explanation

Comment: This is proved in all textbooks on algebraic number theory. @blablah

Comment: @Angina Seng  Could you please tell me the title of the book you have mentioned?

Comment: @blablah See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13282/good-algebraic-number-theory-books for recommendations for texts on algebraic number theory.

Comment: This is proved in Janusz, it proves it for primes, prime powers then by induction on number of prime factors proves it for all m.